# After Importing 60 000 products data My magento Website become Too slow to load

Tags: mysql

Site was working well when I had around 20k of products in MySQL database. Later I have uploaded/imported more data from csv file, I have imported around 60,000 total products. But Now onward, I'm not able to import any more products by same way, Also My website is taking too much time to load around 40-45 sec and sometime browser goes down without loading anything. It just keep loading by showing "waiting for xyz.com" and then by generating an error message "500 internal server error" it goes down.
I have my own dedicated server of good configuration .

CPU GenuineIntel, Intel(R)Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
Version Parallels Plesk Panel v11.0.9_build110120608.16 os_CentOS 6
OS  CentOS 6.4 (Final)
RAM     8gb

I don't know Where is the problem, Is it server Issue or its related to database?
Because its working fine when I have less amount of data but as much as data goes increases , I'm facing more n more problems
So please help me !!

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: Is there a resource that is a bottleneck for the performance? See http://www.brendangregg.com/usemethod.html . Maybe MySQL is slow and adding some indexes would help?

Comment: No there is No any relevant message in logs file. I have checked mysql log file in the server as well as log files in my website but I could not see any such relevant message/error

Comment: @ptman: in magento EAV type database one table is connected to many tables and there is around 400 tables so it is very difficult to know on which tables I should add indexes

Comment: Is this on a VPS, or a physical server?  If the latter, could you post the output of `iostat -x 1` during a slow period?

Comment: Well, does msql not have a decent profiler? Find slow queries, optimize them. EAV type databases are bad for performance - so you may actally want to reconsider that technology choices of yours. Double of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow - the link also has tuning guidelines referenced.

Answer (score 4):

Magento is not really a fast system and your number of products may be taxing it. Especially when not tuned properly. It was built for flexibility, and - that comes with a price.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow

is where you find a lot of explanations and links to tuning guidelines. You may also want a (significantly) larger server for some site of that size (and no, I am not going to copy all those links in here).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is a problem with your database schema.  You should identify columns which are used in selects and joins, and create indices on them.  This tends to slow down insertion time but speed up query time.

You not being able to import additional data might be due to slow queries due to the lack of proper indices, or it might be something else, but start with that.

In general, doing this requires that you actually evaluate your schema and determine how the application is using it.